# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'DepartmentCustomReportController' is not a function, got undefined in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm facing the error only in the Internet explorer , when I try the same controller in the chrome is working just fine. My index.html :

```
<script src="assets/js/boostrapJs/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/boostrapJs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/boostrapJs/ngDialog.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/boostrapJs/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-chart/0.1.0/ng-google-chart.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/boostrapJs/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/boostrapJs/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/boostrapJs/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/boostrapJs/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/sonar/sonarController.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/teamcity/teamCityController.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/tom/tomController.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/admin/adminController.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/kpiEntity/kpiEntityController.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/history/historyController.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/kpiDefinitions/kpiDefinitionsController.js"></script>
<script  src="app/components/customReports/departmentCustomReportController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts-suite-xt/js/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts-suite-xt/js/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts-suite-xt/angularjs-plugin/wrappers/angularjs/angular-fusioncharts.min.js"></script>
```

Also in the js code I defined the controller like below

```
angular.module('dashboardApp').controller('DepartmentCustomReportController', ['$scope','$http', 'baseUrl', 'sharedProperties', 'ngDialog',
function ($scope, $http, baseUrl, sharedProperties, ngDialog) {
```

The problem is like I said only in Internet Explorer 11 , and I am using JavaScript 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I used some Fusion charts libraries and that's why was not working in Internet explorer , because of that I was getting that error in IE ,and in chrome was working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
angular.module('dashboardApp', []);
```

Now, you can either include that in the one liner you have, or separate it out into a variable but either way you need it to be like that. [AngularJS' docs on module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module) are useful.